# Clicking on icons in bottom bar brings page back to top

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Currently, on the iOS SE app, the only way to go back to the top of a page is by scrolling up. This is inconvenient especially for users who are scrolling through old questions and wants to go back to the top.

Can there be a new function so when the button of each page in the bottom bar is clicked (i.e. Questions, Tags and Users), page automatically scrolls back to the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most scroll views on iOS, tapping the status bar (the top bar that holds the time and battery meter etc.) will scroll to the top. There's no need, this already exists.

Comment: Huh. I didn't notice that before. My bad.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 it's a useful thing to know. Works in most apps/views that scroll